# Redesign repository class such that it handles different implementations of request objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service, repository-pattern

I need to redesign an existing application where there is a repository class handling only specific type of object. The object's properties and implementation are specific to only one type.
I need to extend the capability of this repository class such that it can handle requests for different object types having different implementations as tomorrow there can be 'n' number of such objects.

Can someone suggest as to what would be the best way to have such redesign.

The existing design is like below :

```
class SomeClass
{
  string colour {get; set;}
  string type {get; set;}
}


class Service : IService

public void DoWork()
{
    Repository repo = new Repository();
    repo.DoRepoWork();
}

public void DoSomeOtherWork()
{
   Repository repo = new Repository();
   repo.DoSomeOtherRepoWork();
}

class Repository : IRepository
{
  public void DoRepoWork()
  {
     SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();

     obj.Color = "Blue";
     obj.Type = "Line";

     //Implementation specific to only one type of SomeClass Object

  }

  public void DoSomeOtherRepoWork()
  {
     SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();

     obj.Color = "Blue";
     obj.Type = "Line";

     //Implementation specific to only one type of SomeClass Object

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the question is not clear.

1. Are you expecting many type of IService? i.e different types of iService classes.
2. Are you expecting each type of IService to do differnt types of repo work ? i.e repoWork(),DoSomeOtherRepoWork()
3. What is SomeClass. Does each repo work method have their own  SomeClass object? what is the relation ?

Comment: To answer your questions, 1. There is only 1 type of IService 2. Service does many work, for instance repoWork(), DoSomeOtherRepoWork() so on...Currently the repo is catering to only type of SomeClass Object Request. If SomeClass is an animal, you can say it is only implementing the request of "Cat" object. But all types of animals are going to come in future which will need different implementations in repo. 3. Existing RepoWork method is written as generic but inside it is catering to only one type of hardcoded someclass object.

Answer (score 0):

Use factory pattern to return IRepository ojects. Wherein each class in the factory does different kind of repo work. i.e. one class does DoRepoWork() ,other does DoSomeOtherRepoWork()

Let the Service class fetch from the factory based on the "Type of SomeClass". So in future if siblings of SomeClass is created(i.e SomeOtherClass) then you only have to add a new factory class which does SomeOtherClassRepowork